# Multi-touch custom gestures

Tags: android

Android SDK provides Gesture Builder application to create library of custom gestures and `GestureOverlayView` to recognize custom gestures from created library.
But I can create custom gesture only with single finger but multi-strokes.

How can I use these instruments to build and recognize multi-touch custom gestures ?

Example: 
I can create "plus" gesture and recognize it in my app, but i draw "plus" by one finger. I want to recognize "double circles" that can be drawn by two fingers at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Gesture Builder allow to build only ***single touch*** (single stroke & multiple stroke) gestures.

You can't build multi-touch gestures using Gesture builder.
For multi-touch you need to use

**MotionEvent**

Answer (score 0):

```
 gestureOverlay.setGestureStrokeType(GestureOverlayView.GESTURE_STROKE_TYPE_MULTIPLE);
```